# Rotating displays with AppleScript (Monterey)

Tags: applescript, automator, macos-monterey

[Script and the setting window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSANY.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcZqz.png)

How can I click the "Roatation:" button?

Comment: I've submitted an answer below, but next time, please copy and paste your code into the question, and likewise with error messages.

Answer (score 1):

```
tell application id "com.apple.systempreferences"
        reveal pane id "com.apple.preference.displays"
        activate -- This used to not be necessary
end tell

tell application id "com.apple.systemevents" to tell ¬
        process "System Preferences" to tell window 1
        tell (a reference to pop up button -1 of group 1)
                my (wait for it)
                perform action "AXShowMenu"
                tell menu 1
                        my (wait for it)
                        pick menu item 1
                end tell
        end tell
end tell

tell application id "com.apple.systempreferences" to quit

to wait for UIElementRef
        tell application id "com.apple.systemevents" to repeat 10 times
                if the UIElementRef exists then return
                delay 0.5
        end repeat
        error from UIElementRef
end wait
```

You can change the following line:

```
pick menu item 1
```

by replacing the index number `1` with whichever menu item number you require.